# Is dyslexia regarded as a severe disability for academic applications?

Tags: application, nsf

For the [National Science Foundation Graduate Research Fellowship Program](https://www.nsfgrfp.org/) (NSF GRFP) application they ask:

> Other serious disability related to a physical, mental, or emotional
> condition is included in my disability
> (Please specify. Cannot exceed 255 characters.)

Here I listed dyslexia and the academic accommodations I receive. **Is this appropriate?** What do they mean by "Severe Disability".

My case is particularly harsh. In my **Statement of Purpose** I briefly talk about my history of overcoming this as well as how learned to capitalize on my other strengths to compensate for this deficiency. This is particularly important to me, but might not be something that should be mentioned.

This could apply to other academic applications. Is this something that should be mentioned on a PhD application, or is it best to avoid this topic?

Answer (score 3):

Dyslexia is widely recognized as a disability.

Deciding if dyslexia is "severe" is a matter of opinion.  Only one person has a well-informed opinion about the severity of your dyslexia: you.  If you think it is severe, no reasonable person will question it.

Your strategy of mentioning your disability in the context of how you were successful overcoming it is a good strategy.

Comment: I hope to help people in my position. I could have very well dropped out of college if I hadn't been given the right resources. With them I became a straight A student. I know there are others like me that will never get these same resources.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is not one answer that suits all circumstances, as different bodies will ask the question about disabilities for different purposes. You need to be clear in each particular case what information they are needing from you and how that information will be used in their internal processes. Having that clarity will enable you to tailor the information to the needs of the organisation's selection processes.

In the particular example you gave, the [NSF declares that they particularly seek to promote a diverse base for their awards](https://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=6201):

> NSF actively encourages women, members of underrepresented minority groups, persons with disabilities, veterans, and undergraduate seniors to apply.

So you would need to give information that would enable them to determine that you are part of an underrepresented group and  how you have worked to overcome your disability.

In other applications, such as a PhD application, they may ask the information to ensure they have made adequate provision for your interview, or allowed adequate consideration of the writing of your personal statement, or that they have appropriate provision in their research laboratories for you (such as in the case of more severe physical disability). Or equally in a PhD program they may be seeking to implement a positive recruitment program.

Some applicants believe that their application will be prejudiced by giving information on their disability and take the decision to omit that level of detail. I cannot say that this does not happen, but being informed as to the purpose of asking the question gives an applicant more confidence in supplying the level of detail that would enable their application to be well received.

Addressing the topic of dyslexia in particular, there is an increasing base of argument that [dyslexia can give an advantage in certain aspects of intellectual and creative activities](https://www.dyslexicadvantage.org/) but again you probably have no way of determining if that opinion is held by the organising you are applying to or not.